# Adding braces to latex math mode equations

Tags: latex, sympy

I am using [sympy's experimental latex math parser](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html#latex-parsing-functions-reference) in order to compare math equations. However, said parser only permits equations in the form of `\frac{1}{2}` and not `\frac12`. Since I may be dealing with user input, I may need to parse equations in the latter form. If there any method (in python if possible) to convert the latter notation to the former notation, especially as in a single string, the two may be mixed.

Comment: How general do you want to go? Do you want to cover things like `\frac1{2+x}`? How about `\sqrt2`? In the end it might be easier to educate your users ...

Comment: Yeah I suppose.